# High Speed Animation Issue Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an object animated with a high speed animation loop (each animation cycle lasts 0.10 second). The issue I have is in play mode or in mobile device the animation always didn't animate properly, I mean it animate with in a low FPS. How can I solve this?

Comment: Care to give us some more information?  Specifically when you say cycle, do you mean the entire animation is 0.10 seconds long?  also, is tis 2d or 3d?  When you said mobile devices which devices do you mean?  Android devices, iOS devices?  what is your FPS on those devices?

Comment: @Eddge Yes the entire animation is 0.10 seconds, mobile device means both android and IOS.

Comment: 2d or 3d? are you guaranteeing your app is able to maintain the FPS for your animation frames?  Since most android devices lock games to max of 60 fps?

Comment: It's 3D game, I've noticed that when there's is just few objects in the scene it works fine, but when there's a couple tens of objects the issue happen.

Comment: So it sounds like an FPS issue, unfortunately there isn't alot we can do to help you with that possibly look into ways to optimize your rendering this article may help: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/fixing-performance-problems#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b596

I would also suggest checking how you are building to the mobile device, for android I make sure I am doing a 64bit build, there are guides on how to ensure you are doing that.

Comment: Some common causes of FPS issues, are the number of faces your meshes have, texture sizes, not using batch drawing, or GPU instancing.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help